# What happened to Ben Solo's original lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, the-last-jedi

In *The Last Jedi*, we see a flashback of:

> Ben Solo waking up with Luke Skywalker standing over him with his green lightsaber ignited in his hand, and then ignites his own blue lightsaber in fright.

There are plenty of questions and answers about Kylo Ren's spitting red lightsaber with the vents because it's an imperfect Kyber crystal (also the impressive look), but is there any canon information about what happened to his original lightsaber?

Comment: This'll almost certainly be answered in a future work somewhere

Comment: I originally had the impression that that sabre was Luke's/Anakin's original blue one that was lost on Cloud City. I'm not sure if this is the case though

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot It would have been highly unlikely that Ben Solo would have left it behind given his obsession with Darth Vader and it having been his lightsaber, but it's an interesting thought!

Comment: @JaneS It was my thought when I watched the film though now thinking back on it, it seems unlikely. I've just had a look at some blurry pictures of the one Ben uses and I'm now sure it isn't that one but it's not clear enough to tell really.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot it couldn't be the lightsaber that was lost in Cloud City, Maz had that one at the time, per TFA.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not necessarily, Ben could have lost it and then Maz found it. Either way after looking back I don't think it's the same one.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: That implies that Luke found his original lightsaber after losing it in Cloud City (which we know that is not the case) and gave it to Ben to use. On the other hand, part of Jedi training is to build your own lightsaber, and Ben is clearly old enough to have done that by the time he turned on Luke. Either way, like you said, looking at Ben's lightsaber, it doesn't quite look like Luke's anyway.

Comment: If it was Anakin's lightsaber, and Ben went to Maz for help/guidance/refuge after leaving the temple and before fully joining with Snoke, it would explain how it got to Maz's castle. It would also explain both Han's and Ben's reactions to seeing it again in TFA.

Comment: It's also possible it was found by Maz or an associate who returned it to Luke, who used it in the training of his new Jedi (it's true building a light sabre is part of the training, but it seems perhaps Ben's training started late due to Luke's reticence, he may not have reached that stage). Ben surely would have taken the sabre if he had the chance, but given he left Luke alive, perhaps Luke and the sabres were buried together. Afterwards Luke may have returned the sabre to Maz before exiling himself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

His blue lightsaber and his current red one are almost certainly the same one.

Here is a screen cap of his blue lightsaber from the flashback scenes (with an obscuring object digitally removed):

[image]

You can clearly see that it is the same as his current one:

[image]

It has the same pommel, the same small cylinder emitter, the same two slits under the emitter, the same smaller radius handle in the middle, etc.

The obvious changes he has made to it are that the blue one has no emitters for the guard, and has a blue crystal instead of a red one (and it is in way better condition).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a "clean" version of the lightsaber screencap. When the film comes out on Bluray, I've made a note to replace this if you've not already done so

Comment: Good eyes!  It does seem to be the original one modified.  Unless something else comes up later to disprove your answer, I shall accept it! :)

Comment: I'm not sure this proves it's the same one. When Anakin made his second one he made the handles look similar so it could just be that Kylo liked the initial design and replicated it

Comment: Also if it's the same one I'm sure he'd also, more than likely, have the same crystal and design which would mean he wouldn't have needed the side vents.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Really? If you change your haircut are you not the same person anymore? Same applies to a lightsaber.

Comment: @Fatalize The side vents are there because the design is imperfect/crystal is impure (forget which). If it was the same lightsaber both of those wouldn't be an issue. Ergo, it's not the same one.

Comment: I stand by my argument here that the look isn't necessarily evidence that they are the same lightsaber. However, if you want to improve this answer it has since been confirmed in _Star Wars The Rise of Skywalker The Visual Dictionary_ that they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

In the (canon) comic *[Rise of Kylo Ren #4](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Rise_of_Kylo_Ren_4)* we see Ben "[bleeding](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bleeding)" the crystal from his original lightsaber. This process causes it to crack. He then installs this broken crystal back into the original hilt and adds crude vents on either side of the blade emitted to remove the excess energy and create quillons.

**As such, Ben Solo's original lightsaber (and kyber crystal) are in the possession of Kylo Ren, albeit in a modified form.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The new canon way sith get red lightsaber crystals is by making the crystals from Jedi lightsabers “bleed” turning them red so my theory is that when Kylo was turning his crystal red he cracked making him resort adding the quillions (the cross guard) to his handle to release the extra energy so the weapon doesn’t blow up when he ignited it

Comment: Welcome to the site. I recommend taking a look at this [help page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to see what sort of answer we are looking for. Specifically, you've made several claims here as well as putting a theory forward. We prefer if the claims made have some source backing them up, and if you have a valid reason for believing your theory (as opposed to dreaming it up in the shower), we would like to see that thought process as well. To make these changes to your answer, you can use the [edit] button to update it. Good luck.